# Custom Texture and 3d Object

Tags: android, augmented-reality, blender, qcar-sdk

`Vuforia` offers the `ImageTargets` example, but what if I want to create the texture and image myself and import that into Vuforia and Android? Basically is it possible to create my own stones, or chips target and render my own custom 3d teapot? There a lot of question asking the same in this forum bur I haven't seen a plausable solution. The use case would be:

1. Creeate a Custom Texture *Blender
2. Create a Custom 3d image (object) *Blender
3. Using Vuforia have the custom Texture show/view the custom 3d image
4. Using android run the applcation point a device to the printer texture and view the 3d image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuforia has a application that you can login and create your own image targets.